# what is the regular expression for male and female string

Tags: java, regex

I have a url like

```
 /.../Male/...
 or

 /../Female/...
```

Now i want to do something like follows to replace the string's male female part with foo

```
 /../foo/..
```

What is the regular expression for this...
currently i am doing like below but no success

```
url.replace("(fe)?male","foo")
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I don't know java url.replace syntax, but shouldn't it be at least with a capital letter (Female|Male) o matching ignoring cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `replaceAll` to use a regex, and the expression could be even simpler:

```
url.replaceAll("(Fem|M)ale","foo");
```

or

```
url.replaceAll("Female|Male","foo");
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets. And it's not as good as my regex anyway `<pout/>` :)

Comment: @Bohemian Good point - FWIW, I had upvoted your answer a while ago!

Comment: I was pouting over answering first with essentially the same answer (maybe better!) but getting a worse score. There is no justice! Lol. Have another +1!

Comment: @Bohemian Haha - you will have to stick around a little more to hit your rep cap today!

Answer (score 7):

You need `replaceAll()`, which uses *regex* for find what to replace, not `replace()`, which finds plain text:

```
url = url.replaceAll("(fe)?male","foo");
```

Also note that String are immutable, so calling a replace method doesn't *change* the String, it *returns* a *new* String with the changes made, so you must assign the result back to the variable.

A *better* regex would be:

```
url = url.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(fe)?male\\b","foo");
```

The `\b` regex makes sure what's being replaced is the whole *word* female/male. Without `\b` it would replace "male" in "malediction".

The `(?i)` makes the match case insensitive.

Comment: Agreed with the word boundary usage, especially when you capture the male|female as gender in the named group. Eg: `.*(?P<gender>\bmale\b|\bfemale\b).*`

Comment: @SauravKumar that can be simplified to `(?P<gender>\b(?:fe)?male\b)` or even just `(?P<gender>\b(fe)?male\b)` if you don't care about the extra inner capture (although named groups are not supported in java)

Comment: Sorry I missed the Java part in the question :P. Yes indeed it can be simplified as you mentioned. Though I have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214482/regular-expression-to-match-words-in-any-order-but-words-can-be-optional). I hope you can help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `replaceAll` for patterns.

Also you should consider using a case-insensitive pattern, as such:

```
String input = ".../Female/...";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?i)(fe)?male", "foo"));
```

Output:

```
.../foo/...
```